# Passing input to tf.nn.static_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

According to the documentation, the second argument of `static_rnn` should be set to "a length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape `[batch_size, input_size]`, or a nested tuple of such elements."

I passed a list of columns to `static_rnn`, but I get *ValueError: linear is expecting 2D arguments*. So `input_size` can't be 1. What exactly does `input_size` and T refer to? Why can't `input_size` be 1?

It occurs to me that `static_rnn` might expect a list whose matrices contain one-hot vectors. In this case, `input size` would be the vocabulary length. But if `static_rnn` requires one-hot vectors, the documentation would say so, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input_size` denotes the number of the features and it **can be** `1`, e.g, in ordinary time series prediction. You got this error, most probably, because your tensors are `[batch_size]`, not `[batch_size, 1]`.

So, you don't have to one-hot encode your features (though you can), just set the right rank of input tensors.

Sample code:

```py
n_inputs = 1
n_neurons = 5
X0 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])
X1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
output_seqs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(basic_cell, [X0, X1], dtype=tf.float32)
Y0, Y1 = output_seqs
```